# Definite assignment error with nested for loops

Tags: java

**EDIT** Never mind, solved. See solution at the bottom.

The below example is a test question that I need help understanding, and I know it is not standard practice to declare and initialize the for loop counter variable separately.

```java
      int j,k;
  
      for(j=0; j<4; j++)
      {
         for(k = 0; k < 10; k++)
         {
            
         }
      }
      System.out.println(k);
```

This gives a Java compile error "k may not have been initialized", specifically called a *definite assignment error*. Java has a Oracle doc on this error 16-2: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html

However, in those examples the assignment of variables are inside some conditional like an if or while loop.

```
if(true) 
  k = 0;
```

This would also give the same initialization compile error because Java is not 100% certain k will be assigned.
However in my original code, the k for loop is not inside an if or while conditional. As written both loops should always run. In addition, if the k loop was written without it being nested it would compile normally.

The issue is clearly that the nesting of the k loop leads to an initialization error. However, my confusion lies in why there would be uncertainty by the compiler with the assignment of "k." What/*why* exactly about a nested for loop (not qualified by a conditional) would "hide" the assignment of k?

Thank you.

**EDIT** The outer for loop can also be thought of as an if statement. j is initialized, but it is not a guarantee that it will run its block of code, ie enter the inner k loop. For example if the conditional statement in the j loop was `for(j = 0; j < 0; j++)` then j will be initialized but it will not enter its block of code and therefore k will not be initialized. Hence, this possibility of  uncertainty leads to a compiler error.

Comment: I think because of scope the "k" (or "j") in the for loop and the "k" above it are distinct. The k in the for loop stops existing after the loop. Someone may correct me if I'm mistaken about this.

Comment: @RichardKYu No, the inner scope doesn’t redeclare `k`. It’s therefore the same `k`.

Comment: I see now. That's really weird. So the compiler ultimately doesn't understand that this k has been initialized in the for loop?

Comment: @RichardKYu I figured it out, see my edited solution above.

Comment: "Never mind, solved. See solution at the bottom." - If you have solved the problem you shouild post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Arcuvia Thanks for your clarification. It was an insightful question. I have also seen that the same issue does not apply to "j" which further supports your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You’re right that there’s on uncertainty: `k` is definitely going to be initialised. But in order to understand this, the compiler would have to actually understand (or alternatively evaluate) your code.

A compiler may be smart enough to do this for very simple constructs, but *in general* this is impossible, and the Java compiler isn’t smart enough to understand your particular code (the outer loop, to be precise).

To fix the compiler error, you can add an initialisation of `k`:

```
int j, k = 0;
```

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. See my edited solution (let me know if my edited solution is accurate). Also I understand that you can indeed fix the error through initialization of k at the very top, but this was a test question and I wanted to figure out (as it was given) why it was giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's possible, that `k` will not be initialized. `JVM` could check that second loop is empty and will never invoke it. I.e. you could will look like this:

```java
for(j=0; j<4; j++) {}
```

I am not sure that I have described correct JVM behaviour, but I believe it makes sense.

Anyway, I think it's a good practice (from `C++`): define a variable and initialize it right there.